# Apache Airflow - Python Capability Question

Tags: python, bash, airflow

As per the most recent release of Apache Airflow, Airflow 2.0+, and its upgrading documentation found [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/upgrading-to-2.html), Python 3.9 is not supported. However, my understanding is that Python 3.9 is not supported for *running* Apache Airflow, but what about .py files, scripts, etc. written in and libs, modules, etc. built upon Python 3.9?

Can I download Python 3.8 to run Apache Airflow, and via the Bash Operators run Python files that operate on Python 3.9?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `PythonVirtualenvOperator` to run python code in any version you'd like. The operator has `python_version` parameter that you can set.

Example:

```
virtualenv_task = PythonVirtualenvOperator(
    task_id="virtualenv_python",
    python_callable=callable_virtualenv,
    requirements=["requests==2.25.0"],
    system_site_packages=False,
    python_version="2.7" # set to the version you'd like.
    dag=dag,
)
```

You can read about it more in the [docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/operator/python.html#pythonvirtualenvoperator)